# PHP- Carbon Datetime DiffInSeconds and How to Group By Hour

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm calculating difference between 2 datetimes in seconds but I want to group them by hours. It should be like that.

This is how I'm getting difference between 2 dates.

```
$date_diff = $first->created_at->diffInSeconds($second->created_at);
```

And For example first time is 09:47:20 and next one is 11:47:50 I need the group them by hour like this.

```
In 09:00 =  12.40 Minutes
In 10:00 =  60.00 Minutes
In 11:00 =  47.50 Minutes
```

How can I do that ? And what you'll suggest for this ?

Thanks

Comment: I assume the first one should be `12.40 Minutes`.

Comment: quit unclear about differences ? the results seems wrong. you have first time 09:47:20, at 09:00 it should be 47.20 or something else, please describe

Comment: @SagarGautam Its basic I just want to group them by hour  its not complicated and wrong

Comment: you want to calculate difference in date time format Am I right ?

Comment: No I'm already calculating the difference I just divide and group them by hour @SagarGautam

Comment: any suggestion or help for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the code below.

Keep in mind that it works as expected if the start time `<=` the end time.

Also, there's room for improvement, like extracting logic to separate functions or adding trailing/leading zeros where you'd need them, but it should get you started.

```
    $start = '09:47:20';
    $end = '11:47:50';

    $startTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $start);
    $endTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $end);

    $startHour = $startTime->hour; // 9
    $endHour = $endTime->hour; // 11

    $hourRange = range($startHour, $endHour); // array(9, 10, 11)

    if (count($hourRange) === 1) {
        // start and end time share the same hour
        $hourRange = array($startHour, $endHour);
    }

    $lastIndex = count($hourRange) - 1;
    $diffGrouped = array();

    foreach ($hourRange as $index => $hour) {

        if ($index === 0) {

            // start hour has the next full hour - calculate the difference
            $nextFullHour = $startHour + 1;
            $nextFullHourTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H', $nextFullHour);

            $minutes = $startTime->diff($nextFullHourTime)->format('%i.%s');

        } else if ($index === $lastIndex) {

            // end hour is its own "previous full hour"
            $previousFullHourTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H', $endHour);

            $minutes = $endTime->diff($previousFullHourTime)->format('%i.%s');

        } else {

            // everything between the start and the end hour
            $minutes = '60.00';

        }

        $diffGrouped[] = array(
            'hour' => $hour,
            'minutes' => $minutes
        );

    }

    dd($diffGrouped);

    /*
     array:3 [
          0 => array:2 [
            "hour" => 9
            "minutes" => "12.40"
          ]
          1 => array:2 [
            "hour" => 10
            "minutes" => "60.00"
          ]
          2 => array:2 [
            "hour" => 11
            "minutes" => "47.50"
          ]
        ]
    */
```